# Removing lists that contain specific string from list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
print(sentences_fam)

>>>[['30973', 'ok'], 
   ['3044', 'ok'], 
   ['53690', 'fd', '65', 'ca'], 
   ['36471', 'none','good','standing'], 
   ['j6426', 'none'], 
   ['500861', 'm', 'br'], 
   ['j0076', 'none'], 
   ['mf4422', 'ok'], 
   ['jf1816', 'father', '64', 'ca'], 
   ['500854', 'no', 'fam', 'none', 'hx'], 
   ['54480n', 'none'], 
   ['mf583', 'none'],
   ...]

print (len(sentences_fam))
>>> 1523613
```

The lists are of many different lengths and contain all sorts of different strings.
I am trying to remove all lists that contain the keyword 'none'. Based on the list above my desired output should look like this.

```
[['30973', 'ok'], 
['3044', 'ok'], 
['53690', 'fd', '65', 'ca'],  
['500861', 'm', 'br'],  
['mf4422', 'ok'], 
['jf1816', 'father', '64', 'ca'],
...]
```

My list comprehension skills are still not so great so I'm not sure what to do. I have tried converting this list into a dataframe but I have had no luck because each string gets assigned an individual column and I have not found a good way of formatting the data again into a list of lists. I need that type of format to be able to pass the data to the word2vec library.

Basically the whole list is the body of text and each sublist is a sentence. Also please keep in mind that I will be needing to apply this to a large list so performance/efficiency might be important.

Comment: `[s for s in sentences_fam if 'none' not in s]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
filtered_list = [sublist for sublist in sentences_fam if "none" not in sublist]
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think it was that simple!